# Laying out child components using ReactNative and StyledComponents

Tags: react-native, layout, styled-components

I'm trying to apply layout to a set of children in a **ReactNative and StyledComponents context**. My particular problem is that I need to add margins onto all but the last of a set of children in order to take control of the spacing of flex items (all containers are `display: flex` in ReactNative). I don't want to add margin bottom to the components themselves as I think that could get out of hand as the components are required to be re-used in many places.

I've tried a lot of different ways of targeting children in StyledComponents and none have any effect:

- `> *`
- `& > *`
- `.some-class` (`className` is depreciated on ReactNative `View`s)

My best current solution involves wrapping the sets of children in specific Layout handling objects, but this has just moved the responsibility to another child when I feel this is mostly intuitively solved by a parent (which also matches a fundamental principle of the `flex` and `grid` layout specs).

I'm interested to know how this problem has been solved by others so I can do it in the best way possible.

Here is the mark-up I'm trying to layout:

```
<View>
  <Could />
  <Be />
  <Anything />
  <Valid />
</View>
```

Which would render as - each element has an equal margin and the last element has none:

[image]

And this is how I'd do this in vanilla CSS with `flex`:

```
.laid-out {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.laid-out > * {
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
}

.laid-out > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

What is the best practice solution here?

Answer (score 0):

You raise some good points and observations - especially regarding using flex-properties of the parent to space the children with gap, instead of delegating layout to a child of a parent to wrap and add margin there.

I've build out a snack giving a shot at both implementations:
https://snack.expo.io/HyXElYL0V

**First Option: Wrap Each Child and Add Margin:** (GapLayout.js)

Here we simply wrap each child with a View object and add whatever padding/margin to that, excluding the last child if needed.

```
const GapLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <View style={Styles.layoutContainer}>
    {children.map((child, index) => {
      const isLastChild = children.length === index + 1

      return (
        <View style={[Styles.layoutItemWrapper, { marginBottom: isLastChild ? 0 : 8 }]}>
          {child}
        </View>
      )
    })}
  </View>
)
```

This allows the mark-up you outlined above:

```
<GapLayout>
  <WideContent />
  <WideContent />
  <WideContent />
</GapLayout>
```

**Second Option: Set the appropriate Parent Height so that justifyContent: 'space-between' works** (GapLayout2.js)

It would be super ideal to just use **{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }** on the parent, and it works the magic. For it to create space between the elements however, the parent has to be taller than all of the children.

Since we're adding multiple children of unknown length, we need the parent to be of height: unknown length + (number of children - 1) * margin

```
class GapLayout2 extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      contentHeight: null,
    };
  }

  setContentHeight = e => {
    const { contentHeight } = this.state
    const { children, itemMargin } = this.props

    // Return if we already set a contentHeight to prevent an infinite-render-loop.
    if(contentHeight) return

    this.setState({
      contentHeight: e.nativeEvent.layout.height + (children.length - 1) * itemMargin
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const {contentHeight} = this.state

    return (
      <View onLayout={this.setContentHeight} style={[Styles.layoutContainer, contentHeight && { height: contentHeight }]}>
        {children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Whats happening here:

1. We render the parent and all the it's content.
2. We use the onLayout callback to then get the content-height.
3. In setContentHeight, we then setState with the new ContentHeight + margin.
4. Once we have a contentHeight, we then render the parent with the new height:

   **style={[Styles.layoutContainer, contentHeight && { height: contentHeight }]}**

This allows us the same mark-up, without the wrapping of the children.
And I imagine that it'll allow direct children to use flex: 1 / 2/ 10 among each other since they all share the same parent (whereas if they were wrapped, it wouldn't work.)

Would love to see other ideas and implementations.

Cheers,